# Android manifest @integer/google_play_services_version not found

Tags: android, google-play-services

Hi am using eclipse IDE while compiling my project i got an error message in   Android Manifest.xml file.

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: Add google play service library and clean your project.

Comment: Are you using eclipse or android studio? if android studio the did you add the dependency as `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'` in build.gradle

Comment: i am a beginner could you tell me how to add it

Comment: I have just added it below answer

Answer (score 0):

To make the Google Play services APIs available to your app for eclipse:

1. Copy the library project at
   **/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/** to the location where you maintain your Android app projects.
2. Import the library project into your Eclipse workspace. Click `File >
   Import, select Android > Existing Android Code into Workspace`, and
   browse to the copy of the library project to import it.
3. In your app project, reference `Google Play services library` project.
   See [Referencing a Library Project](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) for Eclipse for more information
   on how to do this.

Refer here for more information on setting up play services in your app.

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Now am working in an imported project so there is no build.gradle file

Comment: Ignore that..I thought you are using Android studio..I have corrected my answer for Eclipse

Comment: Welcome...Please mark it `answered` if my answer helped you, so that it helps others in the future with similar problem

Comment: once i get answer i will post it

Comment: I was talking about my answer. I was trying to say if my answer above helped you resolve the issue then you can mark it answered.

Comment: yup its help full for me i solved my errors thank you